# Web application Controller adding items to Queue and consumes elsewhere

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

My application structure looks like this:  WebApp MVC -> Core DLL -> Consumer DLL

WebApp has the Controller with the Post method where I want an item to be added to a Queue.
This Queue needs to be consumed (Dequeue) from the Consumer DLL part.

Core DLL - is currently holding all the Queue code, repository and business code.

The problem I'm having is that I tried using Concurrent queue and had it as a singleton. My idea was to try to make sure I only had one instance of the Queue so the Enqueue and Dequeue was used on the same queue.  This didn't work well.
Seems that as soon as I use Postmand and do a Post and get to the Controller a new thread is created which gives me a new queue thus having the Consumer DLL reading o a totally different queue.

Could anyone maybe give me an idea how to solve this problem, maybe some example if possible.

Thanks

Comment: first of all it would be good if you add some code example of your problem. If you properly register a queue as a singleton you won't have issues with having different queue object for each request to your webapp. Without an example its hard to guide you anywhere. Also its not clear how you provide an instance of the queue to the Consumer dll.

Comment: Did you implement your own queue? Why don't use any of the existing queueing solutions?

Comment: I will try to add some code but meanwhile.  I am using BlockingCollection at this moment.

Comment: You have too many frameworks tagged in this question - please choose the correct platform. Are you using .net core or .net classic? They are not the same.

Comment: I am using .Net Core

Comment: I finally got it working using a singleton.  Got stuck with trying to get it to work. I will add a more detailed question next time. Thanks community